# Count duplicate values in an array

Tags: php, arrays, count, duplicates

I have a series of user data which each one is a list of comma separate values like `italian, english`. So first of all, I want to list each of them and that it is fine and works. But these values could be repeated and it is ok yet I would like to know the number of the repeated values in order to be able to says: `American = 2`. The code below shows me

```
Duplicates count: 5
```

But actually I should have only 2 duplicates as I can see from the admin panel

```
$stack = array();
$blogusers = get_users( 'orderby=nicename&role=author' );
foreach ( $blogusers as $user ) {
    $descTokens = explode(',', $user->user_description);
    $stack = array_merge($stack, $descTokens);
}
$count_values = array();
foreach ($stack as $a) {
    @$count_values[$a]++;
}
echo 'Duplicates count: '.count($count_values);
```

If I do `print_r($count_values)` i get

```
Array (
    [francese] => 1
    [ matematica] => 2
    [ inglese] => 1
    [fisica] => 1
    [ latino] => 1
)
Duplicates count: 5
```

And those aren't repeated strings.

Comment: array_count_value does this for you

Comment: Can you give some examples of the arrays, the actual data?

Comment: @flex_ may you elaborated it in an answer pease?

Comment: @Qirel i have updated the question with the print_r result i get

Comment: So you have 1 duplicate value, which is present two times in your array?

Comment: [array_count_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php)

Comment: This question does not contain an ultra-clear [mcve].  It has been so unfocused that the answers below offer differing results.  We don't need to see the `get_users()` call, we need an array of values with sufficient complexity to differentiate correct answers from incorrect answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this at the end of your code to only have duplicates in $count_values

```
$total_duplicates = 0;
foreach ($count_values as $key=>$count) {
    if($count<=1){
        unset($count_values[$key]);
    }else{
        $total_duplicates += $count;
    }
}
```

This will remove any entries that are not duplicate (occuring once) via unset().
Also $total_duplicates will give you the total count of duplicates.

To output that as html do this:

```
echo '<p>You have '.$total_duplicates.' duplicates.</p>';
foreach ($count_values as $key=>$count) { 
    echo '<li>'.$key.' '.$count.'</li>'; 
}
```

Comment: ok great, this gives me the correct number. Now is it possible to place this result next to each list in order to find out how many of the same are in place? Like `Italian 2`

Comment: with list you mean $stack?

Comment: oh sorry, i mean that then i output them as  <li><?php echo $stack[0]; ?></li> <li><?php echo $stack[1]; ?></li> and ideally I would like to be able to have a count for each

Comment: So $stack[0]; + Num etc will auto generate? Can you elaborate it more in your answer please? I think this is getting right where I what I was looking for

Comment: sure just iterate through $count_values again: foreach ($count_values as $key=>$count) { echo '<li>'.$key.' '.$count.'</li>'; }

Answer (score 2):

Using `array_count_values()` you would get the same output as your secondary `foreach` loop. A `count()` of this would, by your example, give you 5 - francese, matematica, inglese, fisica and latino would be entries with at least 1 as the value and counted as one each (by your example, the index 'matematica' would hold the value 2 instead of 1, as its a duplicate and appears twice, but will still be counted as one).

So if you then filter away all values which appears once, you should get what you're looking for. Use `array_map()` with a callback that removes all values that are one or less would be like this

```
foreach ($blogusers as $user) {
    $descTokens = explode(',', $user->user_description);
    $stack = array_merge($stack, $descTokens);
}
echo array_sum(array_map((function ($v) { return $v > 1 ? $v : 0; }), array_count_values($stack)));
```

[**Live demo**](https://3v4l.org/n4ua7)

---

If you want an array with the values which only appears multiple times, you can replace `array_sum()` with `array_filter()` (that returns an array, so you can no longer echo it directly)

```
print_r(array_filter(array_map((function ($v) { return $v > 1 ? $v : 0; }), array_count_values($stack))));
```

Outputs

```
Array (  
    [twice] => 2  
)
```

See https://3v4l.org/WOObc for a working example on that.

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php

Comment: Using `array_*` functions often simplify working with arrays very much - then you don't have to loop as much, and there's almost always a function suitable for what you need ;-) This can of course be split into more lines, which could help readability of the code.

Answer (score 1):

```
//Count of the duplicate array values 
$count = count(array_count_values($stack));
echo $count;
```

Comment: that gives me 5, it doesn't tell me "you have 2 of this and 3 of that"

Comment: @rob.m you did not ask for "you have 2 of this and 3 of that" in your question. You only complained that the overall number of duplicates is wrong.

Comment: i don't really know if that's possible. but then again i'm not good at arrays

Comment: if i do this i'm almost there  $count_values = array();
 foreach ($stack as $a) {
       @$count_values[$a]++;
 }
 print_r(array_count_values($count_values));

Comment: yet that results number Array ( [1] => 4 [2] => 1  should be placed correctly next to each list results )